# Problem with isorespin on a live usb

Tags: elementary

I have to use isorespin.sh, and I have to launch it on elementary live usb, but when I try to use it, I get this message:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isorespin needs space to unpack the iso, (add/edit some things), then write a new altered iso.  The live media does not have the free space for this, but you can put an ext4 filesystem on a 16G USB disk, (make a directory and) mount it, say at /mnt/iso,
and do the work there.